# R Warning: Mistake in factor

Tags: r

My R code is:

```
means_log_adj <- aggregate(lab_data[,delta_touse], 
    by = list(
        factor(mydata_adj$Response_EP, labels = c("non_responder", "responder")), 
        factor(mydata_adj$sex,labels = c("male","female")), 
        factor(mydata_adj$timepoint,labels = c("baseline","wk1","wk2","EP"))),
    mean)

Warning message: 
> mistake in factor
> (mydata_adj$Response_EP, labels =
> c("non-responder", "responder")):
> invalid labels; length 2 should be 1
> or 0.
```

Could anybody help me to solve my problem?

Comment: A reproducible example (i.e.: the actual data or part of it) would be nice. However, it appears your Response_EP only holds 1 value (perhaps there are only responders?)

Comment: It's not obvious to me what your problem is.  If this is a warning, not an error, then your code will still run and produce results.  Are the results not what you expected?  Please post sample data and expected results so we can help you.

Answer (score 14):

After some trial and error I managed to reproduce your problem.

But let me start by saying that there is a very important difference between a `warning` and an `error` in R.  When you report a problem, be sure to distinguish clearly between the two.

```
x <- letters[1:5]
factor(x, labels=LETTERS[1:10])

Error in factor(x, labels = LETTERS[1:10]) : 
  invalid labels; length 10 should be 1 or 5
```

This error occurs because you are telling `factor()` to re-label the data with levels that don't exist.  I have specified 10 labels for a variable that only contains 5 levels.  This means the labels and levels don't match.

There are two ways to fix this:

The first is to let R determine the levels, and simply call `factor(x)` without any parameters.  (At a guess, this is probably what you should have done in your code.):

```
factor(x)
[1] a b c d e
Levels: a b c d e
```

The second is to call `factor(x)` and specifying the `levels`, not the `labels`:

```
factor(x, levels=letters[1:10])
[1] a b c d e
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

---

You haven't provided sample data, so we can't test a solution.  But try the following code:

```
means_log_adj <- aggregate(lab_data[,delta_touse], 
    by = list(
        factor(mydata_adj$Response_EP,), 
        factor(mydata_adj$sex), 
        factor(mydata_adj$timepoint)),
    mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Andrie on Jun 20 '11 at 12:48

In the example provided as:

```
factor(x)
[1] a b c d e
Levels: a b c d e
```

count the number of levels in the result set. Here there are 5 so you can set your ratio to 1:5. This works well when executing bubbleMap's key.entries variable. When I get this error, the first thing I do is what was prescribed by Andrie and update the ratio with the number of levels displayed.