# Why do I keep getting the error "invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 3"

Tags: r, dataset

I'm new to R and I'm hitting a wall trying to figure this out.

I'm using a dataset from Perry Undem and all of the variables either have values of `1` or `2` (`yes` or `no`) or have values such as `1 (agree)` to `5 (strongly agree)`.

For example:

> qn8 - Do you have a favorable or unfavorable view of Trump right now?

I put this code in:

```
table(finaldata$qn8) 

finaldata$qn8 <- factor(finaldata$qn8, labels = c("favorable view", "unfavorable view"))
```

and this error comes up:

```
finaldata$qn8 <- factor(finaldata$qn8, labels = c("yes", "no"))
Error in factor(finaldata$qn8, labels = c("yes", "no")) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 3
```

What do I do here?

Comment: try `factor(c(0,1,2), labels=c("a", "b"))` to reproduce the error : this suggests `qn8` has 3 values. Look at `unique(finaldata$qn8)`

Comment: maybe of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506239/r-warning-mistake-in-factor

Comment: it worked. thank you !

Comment: you're welcome. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate, as I'm assuming this was a similar problem to ^^.